# Store JSON array on Redis

Tags: javascript, json, redis

I have the following JSON array in javascript:

```
[
    {
        title: 'Title 1',
        description: 'Description 1',
        startTime: 'Start time 1',
        duration: 5,
        humidity: 50
    },
    {
        title: 'Title 2',
        description: 'Description 2',
        startTime: 'Start time 2',
        duration: 15,
        humidity: 30
    },
    {
        title: 'Title 2',
        description: 'Description 2',
        startTime: 'Start time 2',
        duration: 10,
        humidity: 40
    }
]
```

I need to store it on a Redis storage. I need to be able to retrieve the entire array most of the times, but sometimes I need to get an specific entry. In SQL I can create an "ID" with autoincrement, and store each entry in a row.
But which is the best method to accomplish this with Redis?

Thanks!

Comment: tried using hashes like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6278398/2314308 ?

Comment: Will you know the index of the item you want to retrieve (ie does the "ID" correlate directly to it's position in the array)?  You can query Redis for items at specific locations in lists, but you need to know the position to do so (as opposed to SQL, where you could say "give me the row with ID=x, regardless of where it is in the table")

Comment: At the moment I don't have an ID for each field, but I can add one (but it's a little tricky because I will need to maintain the correlation of the IDs manually when with SQL this is automatic. It makes me think that I'm doing this wrong. I can store the json array as string and retrieve the full string each time, with this I will fix most of my problems, but I can't identify an specific array entry

Answer (score 0):

I'm saving the same structure in Redis. This is optimized for when you need to retrieve all the data in JSON format with RedisJSON. So for example to save the structure:

```
const tagsArray = {
      id: '101',
      qc: 3,
      ts: '2022-07-07T14:36:14.712Z',
      val: 10.332507886284837,
      tag: 'DB_right.Corrente'
    },
    { ... },
    { ... }
 }
```

I'm using the code (eg. Node.js with redis npm module):

```
const redisClient = createClient()
await redisClient.connect()
await redisClient.json.set('arr:key', '$', [])
await redisClient.json.arrAppend('arr:key', '$', {searchKey: tagsArray})

const r = await redisClient.json.get('arr:key')
console.log('@R >> ', r)
```

Where you can build a searchKey for each element in the JSON array you will fill with the items!